# adding admob in relative layout overlapping button

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, admob, ads

I have problem with an Admob ad overlapping the button and text view field in my Relative Layout. How do I get it below the enter text field and button area?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".Chat_Room">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/room_name_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_add_room"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_add_room"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_room"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Select group above"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/room_name_edittext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_add_room"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I put the adview bottom of the screen below edit text and button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your Button: `android:layout_above="@+id/add"`

and remove: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add_room"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/add"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="Select group above" />
```